# Nested Multifield loop not working in AEM JS files

Tags: javascript, foreach, aem

I have a dialog where there is nested multifield. In the nested multifield, there's dropdown and other fields (that needs to be validated).

---

Details of the dialog:

Multifield

Container (name = Parent)

```
 Multifield

      Container (name = Child)

          dropdown (class = cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide-multi)
              TextField
```

---

Javascript code for looping :

```
(function ($, document, ns) {

   const A = function () {
         console.log("In A");
      $(this).find("[data-granite-coral-multifield-name='./Child'] .coral3-Multifield-item").each(function( index ) {
         console.log("In Loop");
      })
  };

  $(document).on("change", ".cq-dialog-dropdown-showhide-multi", function() {
      A();
  });

  $(document).on("dialog-ready", function() {
      A();
  });

})(Granite.$, document, Granite.author);
```

---

Function A gets called once the dialog content has loaded (on opening the dialog).

Function A gets called when there is a change in dropdown value.

---

Suppose, my parent multifield has 1 item and its child multifield has 2 items:

Func A gets called when the dialog is opened and "In A In Loop In Loop" gets printed in console. Now if I change the dropdown value, func A gets called again, but this time only "In A" gets printed in console. The loop doesn't get executed even though the number of child items are still the same.

Not sure what exactly may be the issue. Please advice.

Comment: Do console log for `$(this)` and check which dom element it's referring to.

Comment: Getting an collapsible data like this:     jQuery.fn.init(1)
0: Window {0: Window, 1: Window, 2: Window, 3: Window, 4: Window, 5: Window, 6: Window, 7: Window, 8: Window, 9: Window, 10: Window, 11: Window, window: Window, self: Window, document: document, name: "", location: Location, …}
length: 1
__proto__: Object(0)

Answer (score 2):

The above started working after a correction in the line:

```
$(this).find("[data-granite-coral-multifield-name$='Child'] .coral3-Multifield-item").each(function( index ) {
```